# Import library into Intellij Idea for a Groovy script (XmlParser or XmlSplurper)

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, xml-parsing

First of, I am a totally new to Java/Groovy.

I am trying to use the XmlSlurper library ([Link to doc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html)) in a Groovy script.

- I imported the library using `File > ProjectStructure > Libraries`.
- Then I added "groovy-xml-2.5.7-indy".
- After adding the library I can `ctrl + click` on the import and see the XmlSlurper Class.
- Then, when I run the script, I get the following compiler

Error:

```
Executing task 'build'...
:compileJava NO-SOURCE
startup failed:
D:\MY_PATH_TO_PRJ\Script.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class groovy.util.XmlSlurper
@ line 3, column 1.
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper^
```

The code I am trying to compile is the simplest in the world:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher 
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
```

Is there anything I would've missed along the way? 

Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Comment: May be you should try adding https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.17/groovy-all-2.4.17.jar to classpath instead the one you have. Groovy does not ship single jar from groovy 2.5 onwards.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! The classpath was a great hint! After some hours of banging my head against the wall, I finally found the solution which seems now like an obvious answer. Adding the library inside File>ProjectStructure couldn't work. I had to modify the gradle build script to compile the xml library. I should have meybe mentioned in the question that I was using Gradle, but I didn't know the use of it until today... Thanks again!